# Class or ArrayList?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made a weather app that receives information from an api. I have a class like that:

```
public class Forecast
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string day_name { get; set; }
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public int degree { get; set; }
    public int degreemax { get; set; }
    public int degreemin { get; set; }
    public string condition { get; set; }
}
```

The class helps me to hold data. Also I can hold data with ArrayList, not necessarily class. I know that I should use classes. However, I am wondering which one is more efficient.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: And how would you store this data in ArrayList?

Comment: `ArrayList` is an obsolete collection class; try not use it at all!

Comment: I would suggest to use a class. This makes further work like calculations or statistics easier to implement and the code is better readable and maintainable

Comment: Your class is fine, but how do you intend on storing multiple Forecasts? You could declare a List of type Forecast to do that, e.g. List<Forecast> = new List<Forecast>().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scenario, anytime I would prefer a class over an ArrayList. The following are the positives I can think of right now

1. **Intellisense** - you will have date, etc in intellisnse. Whereas in arraylist you would need to remember on which location you have entered what data
2. **boxing-unboxing** - arraylist adds values in object so if you are putting int values, they will be boxed
3. **Multiple Forecasts** - If you want to store many Forcasts then it is not possible using arraylist or at least it will be 1 hell of a time for you to maintain it. It can be easily implemented with classes using `List<yourClass>`
4. **Performance** - Class is anytime better performing than ArrayList
5. **More functionality** - You can add methods to a class to extend its functionality like some calculations, etc. To have more functionality to `ArrayList` you would need to create a custom class inheriting from `ArrayList` and write your functionality there so ultimately you are using a class only.
6. **OOPS concepts** - All OOPS concept apply to a class like inheritance hence extending the functionality to other classes, etc. Not possible with ArrayList

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that your answer is more than enough:)

Comment: @rosko; thanks. Just wanted to be a little exhaustive so that the OP never thinks of an ArrayList ever in these scenarios. :)